# Ajax.Beginform refreshing whole page

Tags: ajax, partial-views

It redirects to whole new page instead of just updating the current one, I have unobtrusive scripts and web.config stuff. Why is this not working?

```
<div id="preview-image-placeholder"></div>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    using (Ajax.BeginForm("PreviewImage/" + @item.Id.ToString(), "Music", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "preview-image-placeholder" },
                                                      new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data", @item.Id }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <input type="file" class="upload-image" id="upload-image-file_@item.Id" name="file" accept="image/*">
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="btn-preview_@item.Id" style="display: none" type="submit"></button>
    }
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

Controller:

```
     [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
     [HttpPost]
        public PartialViewResult PreviewImage(HttpPostedFileBase file, int id)
        {
            //Do other code stuff
                return PartialView("_DisplayImage", song);
        }
```

_DisplayImage partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MusicSite.Models.UploadedSong>
@using MusicSite.CustomHtmlHelpers;

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    if (@item.CoverImageBytes != null)
    {
        @Html.ImageFor(x => item.CoverImageBytes, @item.SongName + " Image", new { @id = "preview-image" })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides unobtrusive scripts you must add Microsoft Ajax libraries too (MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcAjax.js) so that Ajax.BeginForm works correctly.

Regards,